# Subprocess terminating when Python exits when using disown in i3

Tags: python, linux, process

I currently have the following setup:

in i3 config:

```
bindsym $mod+d exec xfce4-terminal --title="Supermenu" -e "path/to/supermenu"
for_window [title="Supermenu"] floating enable
```

The script it executes is a Python script executable (using a shebang and chmod +x), that has this line (among a lot of others, which have nothing to do with it):

```
os.system(command + " >/dev/null 2>&1 &")
```

My expectation, is that when the Python script exits, the process called by `command` should stay running, because of the `&`. However, it still exits once the xfce4-terminal exits! (which happens after the script terminates obviously).

I also tried sticking `disown` at the end and `nohup` at the beginning, both made no difference.

I can confirm it happens when the script exits, because I tried using `time.sleep` to see if it even launches, and yes it does - but terminates after the terminal closes.

**However, if I launch `firefox` or `ghetto-skype`, they do terminate, however, an `xfce4-terminal` does not terminate after the "menu" closes!**

**And even weird - if I launch the script from an xfce4-terminal (instead of with i3), the subprocess will not terminate either!**

I am very confused as to what is going on, and would appreciate any help with understanding it, and prevent the processes other than `xfce4-terminal` from closing after the menu does.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't redirecting standard input.  I'm guessing it gets an EOF when `xfce4-terminal` closes.

Comment: Worked, however I also needed to add a `time.sleep(0.1)` after the `system` for some reason... I will accept the answer but please add that in for future visitors

Comment: Update: doesn't work with `eclipse` even with a longer sleep, closes as soon as terminal closes...

Comment: @TheSuperCuber Note that you can answer your own question once you figure a solution out yourself.

Comment: @dorukayhan if I figure out a solution